# Top K Frequent Elements - How to Reverse Elements

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue, word-frequency

I've included a picture of the problem below that explains it in more detail. The goal is to just find the k highest occurrences in a dictionary of words. My approach is getting the frequency in a HashMap and then using a Priority Queue to store the max k elements. I then add the max k elements to my return list and return it.

For the given input in the picture, my code returns to correct output -
["i","love"]. The problem is for inputs like the one below:

```
input: ["the", "day", "is", "sunny", "the", "the", "the", "sunny", "is", "is"]
output: ["day","sunny","is","the"]
expected: ["the","is","sunny","day"]
```

The correct answer would just be a reverse of my current string, however if I reverse the string before returning the original input (the one in the picture) no longer works.

I think this had something to do with how the values are being store in the priority queue when their frequency is the same...but I'm not sure of to check for that.

Any thoughts on how I could fix this?

[image]

```
class Solution {
    public List<String> topKFrequent(String[] words, int k) {
       HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
       List<String> mostFrequent = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if(map.containsKey(words[i])) {
                map.put(words[i], map.get(words[i]) + 1);
            }
            else {
                map.put(words[i], 1);
            }
        }
        
        PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>((a,b) -> map.get(a) - map.get(b));
        
        for(String s : map.keySet()) {
            pq.add(s);
            if(pq.size() > k) {
                pq.remove();
            }
        }
        
        for(String s : pq) {
            mostFrequent.add(s);
        }
        
        //Collections.reverse(mostFrequent);
        
        return mostFrequent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve is by changing your code like below,

```
class Solution {
    public static List<String> topKFrequent(String[] words, int k) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> mostFrequent = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if(map.containsKey(words[i])) {
                map.put(words[i], map.get(words[i]) + 1);
            }
            else {
                map.put(words[i], 1);
            }
        }

//Below I am sorting map based on asked condition and storing it into the list.
        List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> sorted = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(sorted,(Map.Entry<String,Integer> x,Map.Entry<String,Integer> y) -> x.getValue().compareTo(y.getValue()) == 0? x.getKey().compareTo(y.getKey()):x.getValue().compareTo(y.getValue()) > 0 ? -1 : 1 );

        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : sorted) {
            mostFrequent.add(e.getKey());
        }

        return mostFrequent;
    }
```

Here, after creating the frequency map I am sorting them based on frequency and creating one new `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it. But you have a few bugs.
At first, your solution is not full. In original task they asked not only about frequency but additional, if frequency is equal - output elements in alphabetical order.
To achieve that you can use following comparator for PriorityQueue:

```
PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>((a, b) -> {
    int countComparison = Integer.compare(map.get(a), map.get(b));
    if (countComparison == 0)
        return b.compareTo(a);
    return countComparison;
});
```

And, the next mistake with your solution is iterating over PriorityQueue. PriorityQueue iterator does not guarantee any particular order. From the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order.

Because of it you need to poll elements from the queue. And part responsible for it:

```
while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
   String s = pq.poll();
   mostFrequent.add(s);
}
```

And final part - because of the order of elements in queue(from the lowest to the highest) you need to reverse output array:

```
Collections.reverse(mostFrequent);
```

The final solution will look like this:

```
public List<String> topKFrequent(String[] words, int k) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> mostFrequent = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if(map.containsKey(words[i])) {
            map.put(words[i], map.get(words[i]) + 1);
        }
        else {
            map.put(words[i], 1);
        }
    }

    PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>((a, b) -> {
        int countComparison = Integer.compare(map.get(a), map.get(b));
        if (countComparison == 0)
            return b.compareTo(a);
        return countComparison;
    });

    for(String s : map.keySet()) {
        pq.add(s);
        if(pq.size() > k) {
            pq.remove();
        }
    }

    while(!pq.isEmpty()) {
        String s = pq.poll();
        mostFrequent.add(s);
    }
    Collections.reverse(mostFrequent);

    return mostFrequent;
}
```